# PHP script hangs on local IP change

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script that connects to remote MySQL host to perform some queries.
After some time it hangs with a message 'MySQL server has gone away'.
I have a dynamic IP that changes at least 3 times per day and I realized it hangs at the time of IP change.

So I have altered the script to detect this error, wait 30 - 90 seconds and reconnect to the server, but now it hangs on that reconnect attempt.

This happens on both linux and windows.

What could be the cause of this?

EDIT: I thought it was obvious, but the IP that changes is the local IP where the script is running, the MySQL server is on a fixed ip. Local pc is connected to ADSL router and I guess my ISP is forcing the reconnects (ip change).
I'm aware that on IP change all existing connections are lost, incl. MySQL, but I said I am RECONNECTING on IP Change and it fails to reconnect!

Comment: You have already answered your question.  When your IP changes, all existing connections are lost.

Comment: TCP connections (such as that to the MySQL server) won't persist across IP changes.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show us some code so we can see whats going wrong.

Comment: @Brad please read the entire question, OP said he changed the script to detect this and do a reconnect.

Comment: Do you try to close the older connection first?
    mysql_close();
Doubtful, but worth a try

Comment: Show the code for the (re)connection script and/or function.

Comment: Also important: Which IP is changing .. the servers or the clients?

Comment: @Kaii, I did read the whole question.  When the server IP changes, the connection is lost.  On reconnecting, all sorts of things can go wrong, but he didn't provide enough details to further debug that issue.  For instance, is he changing networks with that IP change?  How about dynamic DNS?  Or, as you have pointed out, it's possible he's referring to the client changing IPs, and not the server.

Comment: @Brad thats right - but the dying TCP connection may not stop his script from working .. as you now pointed out, it depends on the circumstances. just wanted to say that.

Comment: @Kaii, Ah, I understand the confusion now.  Yes, I completely agree.

Comment: you should ask your ISP for a fixed IP or search about dyndns solution

Comment: thanks for the responses, I have edited the question. @William Isted: yes I am doing a mysql_close() before the reconnect

Answer (score 1):

How are you getting the new IP address?  If you are using DNS (including dynamic DNS), my guess would be that you are hitting a stale DNS cache.  Even most dynamic DNS entries of a TTL of longer than 90 seconds (and some intermediate caching servers might set a minimum TTL anyway).

Comment: I'm not sure how DNS matters here, I'm using the IP (not domain name) of remote server to connect and that is a fixed IP

Comment: @MarioLjubicic Ah, sorry, I see your edit to the question clarifying that it's the *client* IP that changes. I had interpreted your original question to mean that the *server* IP was changing.  I'm going to leave my response here, though, for the benefit of anyone who finds your question via search.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for this behavior can be persistent database connections. To clarify if this is the case, please restart your Apache or IIS Web server in case the IP address has been changed. If everything works fine after the restart you got it.

[Persistent database connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php) are stored in the background and reused if host name and user credentials of the database connection are matching. The mysql library makes a difference: [mysql_pconnect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php) for persistent and [mysql_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) for non persistent connections.

Additionally you can check your php.ini for the setting of **mysql.allow_persistent**.

Comment: Persistent connections are enabled, but I'm not using persistent connections!